# how do I retrieve data from html between two words using with vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net

suppose that I have html file which is include ;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="blanket">
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<br />
      An acre is the area of a rectangle whose length is one furlong and whose width is one chain.
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get data from between "div"  tags ,

```
    Dim StrData As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    Dim pos1 As String, pos2 As String, getDataHTML As String
    pos1 = InStr(StrData, "<div id=" & Chr(34) & "blanket" & Chr(34) & ">" , vbTextCompare)
    pos2 = InStr(StrData, "</div>" , vbTextCompare)
```

I tried some codes but no solution .

```
getDataHTML = StrData.Substring(pos1, pos2)
```

or

```
getDataHTML = Strings.Mid(StrData, pos2 - pos1, 15)
```

any solutions for get data from between div tags ??

Comment: You are wanting the substring that starts at position `pos1+18-1` (zero-based) and is `pos2-pos1-18` characters long, so `getDataHTML = StrData.Substring(pos1+18-1, pos2-pos1-18)` should do it.  (`18` represents how many characters from the start of `<div ...` to the first character you are after.)

Comment: Using a WebBroswer control or HtmlAgilityPack find the element and use its inner text.